# BullMQ: How to schedule and execute a job once at a specific timestamp in the future without using delay?

Tags: javascript, node.js, queue, worker, bullmq

is there a built-in way in `bullMQ` to schedule a `job` to execute at a specific timestamp in the future?

I know it can somehow be done with:

```
const targetTime = new Date('03-07-2035 10:30');
const delay = Number(targetTime) - Number(new Date());

await myQueue.add('house', { color: 'white' }, { delay });
```

but why it needs to calculate the relative time with:

```
const delay = Number(targetTime) - Number(new Date());
```

instead of taking a `timestamp` / `unix timestamp` directly?

If I add a `job` to the `queue` and then I want to schedule it, should I define the `worker` everytime to make it run?